# How to pass dictionary or JSON to Invoke-AzVMRunCommand - Parameter?

Tags: linux, bash, azure, powershell, devops

I have a Input file which I read in a env variable InputConf.

```
[ {     "name": "administrators",     "description": "Default group for DSS administrators",     "sourceType": "LOCAL",     "admin": true,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,     "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": false,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-se-npr",     "description": "ElevatedSupport",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-se-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": true,     "mayManageUDM": true,     "mayCreateProjects": true,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": true,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": true,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": true,     "mayWriteUnsafeCode": true,     "mayWriteSafeCode": true,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": true,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": true,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": true,     "mayEditLibFolders": true,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": true,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": true,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": true,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": true,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-au-npr",     "description": "Auditor",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-au-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,     "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": false,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-ba-npr",     "description": "BusinessAnalyst",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-ba-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,     "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": false,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-ds-npr",     "description": "DataScientist",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-ds-npr",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,         "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": true,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-dsfe-npr",     "description": "DataScientistFeatureEnhancement",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-dsfe-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,         "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": true,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": true,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-ls-npr",     "description": "LeadScientist",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-ls-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": true,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,         "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": true,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-sp-npr",     "description": "Support",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-sp-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": true,     "mayCreateProjects": true,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": true,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": true,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": true,         "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": true,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": true,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": true,     "mayEditLibFolders": true,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": true,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-rm-npr",     "description": "ReleaseManager",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-rm-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,         "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": false,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" }, {     "name": "dss-te-npr",     "description": "Tester",     "ldapGroupNames": "dss-te-npr",     "sourceType": "LDAP",     "admin": false,     "mayManageUDM": false,     "mayCreateProjects": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromMacros": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromTemplates": false,     "mayCreateProjectsFromDataikuApps": false,         "mayWriteUnsafeCode": false,     "mayWriteSafeCode": false,     "mayCreateAuthenticatedConnections": false,     "mayCreateCodeEnvs": false,     "mayCreateClusters": false,     "mayDevelopPlugins": false,     "mayEditLibFolders": false,     "mayManageCodeEnvs": false,     "mayManageClusters": false,     "mayViewIndexedHiveConnections": false,     "mayCreatePublishedAPIServices": false,     "mayWriteInRootProjectFolder": false,     "mayCreateActiveWebContent": false,     "canObtainAPITicketFromCookiesForGroupsRegex": "" } ]
```

I need the variable to be copied to the Linux VM - /dss/data/groups.txt

I call the script using Invoke-AzVMRunCommand using RunShellScript

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VirtualMachineName -CommandId RunShellScript -ScriptPath "$($PSScriptRoot)/scripts/$PatchScript"  -Parameter @{InputConfParam=$InputConf}
```

In the script, I do the below

```
echo $InputConf > /dss/data/groups.txt
```

However I do not get the entire string, but only get the first character of the InputString.
This is because of the spaces/tabs in the variable.

Is there a way I can get the entire JSON passed to the shell script? so I can copy the variable to the file on the server?

Thanks

Comment: I would upload JSON file to blob storage, then have shell script download file with `curl`/`wget` to `/dss/data/groups.txt`.

Comment: *However I do not get the entire string, but only get the first character of the InputString.* ... I very much doubt that. If I copy that JSON string and paste it into `export InputConf='...'` followed by a `echo $InputConf > groups.txt` I get the lot ... maybe there's a buffering issue when capturing the variable?

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. Do you mean to read your local env variable into the parameter and execute the script in the VM to write the parameter to the file?

Comment: Could this be simply just a case of putting the $InputConf variable in quotes when redirecting to groups.txt?

Comment: Enclosing $InputConf in quotes does not work. What is expected, is the script reads the variable and writes it to a file on the VM. Pretty straightforward - if you hardcode and run the script directly on the server and works well also. It just causes a pain when executed through the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a very crude workaround or replacing the newline chars and spaces and sending the parameter to the shell script and replacing it back in the script.
Blob Storage was a good option - will surely try the approach.